# Как в Python создать формулу в символьном виде, сохранив её в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Как в Python создать формулу в символьном виде и сохранить в файле pdf или в формате изображения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться одним из многочисленных вэб-сервисов для рендеринга изображения формулы на основе [LaTeX Markup](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics), например [latex codecogs](https://latex.codecogs.com/).

Ваш пример, записанный в этой разметке выглядит как:

```
y_{1} = x^{2}
```

Сформировать запрос для создания png, например:

```
http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\dpi{300}&space;\bg_white&space;y_{1}&space;=&space;x^{2}
```

и сохранить как картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть методами самого языка результат не получить?

Comment: @ZenAndrew свежих библиотек не нахожу

Comment: matplotlib поддерживает LaTeX в подписях.